# How to Find every other odd number from 0 to 9

Tags: c

Hello all I have been trying to get every other odd number from 0 - 9 and I almost got it working but for some reason It's giving me 3 and 7 instead of 3, 7 ,and 9 the I went about solving it like so :

```
    int i = 0;
    int count = 1;
    for (; i < 10; i++)
    {
        if (i & 1)
        {
            count++;//add one if i is odd

            if (count & 1)//if count is odd then its the next odd
                printf("%d\n", i);//print i
        }

    }
```

Comment: 3, 7, & 9 would not be every other odd number. It should either give you 3 & 7, or 1, 5, & 9 depending on whether the first odd counts or not.

Comment: Note that you could also reduce this to starting with 3 (or 1) and adding 4 each time around the loop, rather than testing every integer. But that probably isn't what your teacher is looking for, since they want you to learn a more general approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a more general solution that simplifies your algorithm a bit.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {

    int max = 10;
    int first_odd = 3;
    int remainder = (first_odd % 4);
    for(int i = first_odd; i <= max; i++) {
        // every other odd is separated by 4, 
        // and will thus have the same remainder by 4
        if(i % 4 == remainder) {
            printf("%d\n", i); // prints 3, 7
        }
    }

    return 0;

}
```

Or, as @keshlam said, you could just hard-code it:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int max = 10;
    int first_odd = 1; // or 3
    for(int i = first_odd; i <= max; i += 4) {
        printf("%d\n", i); // prints 1, 5, 9
    }
    return 0;
}
```